# How can I change my shell language localization on the macOS command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, internationalization, zsh

I have a Mountain Lion macbook and it's default locale is english, it's keyboard is english (US) as well. I need to change the language that the terminal replies to Swedish.

For example,
Instead of replying "Connection Refused" for a failed telnet, it should say "Forbindelse Vagras" (which is the Swedish translation)

EDIT:
I have tried setting LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8 and same with LC_ALL, to no effect

Have also tried changing system-wide settings, which changes the language in the entire system but not the zsh shell.

Is this split localization possible on macOS?

Comment: I don't think command-line tools like `telnet` are localized.

Comment: so i'll have to get extra language packs?

Comment: I don't think there are any extra language packs :) Everything is already shipped with OS X; these tools simply were never localized. The only command-line tool that ships some locale info is `/usr/bin/cal`; if you type `LANG=sv_SE cal` in Terminal you will get weekday names in Swedish. That's as far as you get.

Comment: Bah! Any ideas about other OSs? Windows, Ubuntu... I can install a VM and test what I need to.

Comment: Windows is definitely the best at this, all standard components should be perfectly localized, but it's command-line environment is not POSIX and lacking features to the degree of pathetic. Try also FreeBSD, RedHat/Fedora (you may need to install additional packages having "nls" in their name).

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal enter

```
export LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

You can add that to `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` for zsh) in order to change the language for all terminal sessions.

All command line tools that are localized should now print the output in Swedish.

However, those command line tools that were built without localization but use hard-coded texts cannot be changed in any way (except on source code level, of course), your example `telnet` being one of them.

Comment: This is the correct thing to do but as the comments show this does not solve the OP's issue. Most POSIX command are hard coded to report in English

Comment: You're right. I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Virtualization is clearly what OP needs here since they can’t change the entire macOS locale. Forgive any typos in my edit.

Comment: @bmike I don't think your edit is correct. If tools are built with hard-coded English texts, virtualization makes no difference whatsoever. My macOS is set to German, and some command line tools still print their output in English.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you'll want to set the `LANG` environment variable.

Comment: tried that... it shows LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="sv_SE.UTF-8" but the language remains stubbornly english